# how to constraint field value from another field in another module in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

i want to constraint the field value, but the another field is from another module, the field is delay_id, and the another field from another module is delay,like example delay value is 10, and when i want to add value in delay_id the number cant surpass 10, and so i use this

```
    @api.constrains('delay_id')
def _check_delay_id(self):
    for record in self:
        bahan = self.env['product.supplierinfo'].search([('delay', '<',record.delay_id),('id', '=',record.id)])
        if bahan:
            raise ValidationError("Delivery Lead Time more than Delivery Lead Time Vendor Pricelist")
```

but it doesnt work,
is there any solutions?

Comment: can you please add more code and also explain this `('id', '=',record.id)`
this will search in product.supplierinfo module with id same as your current record

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.